# APIs are to be protected by wso2 Identity server

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I want to secured my all APIs (created by wso2 APIm) by wso2 Identity server.

Could you please let me know how to do configuration set up ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can configure WSO2 Identity Server as the key manger of APIM. Refer [1].

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Configuring+WSO2+Identity+Server+as+a+Key+Manager